# Is this possible to redirect the tty output to two targets?

Tags: terminal, tty

I would like to let the tty to have two outputs. Is this possible to let the output display on two terminal?

I would like to have one terminal (on Linux), which is I am working on, and redirect(/duplicate) the same output the another electric device. (LED screen, for example.)

Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what you're doing unless you tell us. Is this a question about how to do this with some particular shell? If so, what shell? It's probably possible, but without knowing what tools you're using or even what operating system you're asking about, how could we help you? (Also, choice of tags is poor containing only redundant information already in the question. Helpful tags would be things like `Windows` or `bash` that give us *useful* information about the context your problem occurs in or the expertise needed to answer it.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you use, you might be able to use [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) to split your output between the standard out (AKA the terminal) and a second stream, then pipe the second stream into whatever sends the electronic device its commands.

You'd use something like `programoutput | tee outputfile | device` I believe.